# Windows 8: Simultaneously use Wifi and Wireless Broadband - routing

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, routing

I have the following situation in Win 8: Internet-Connection is provided by a USB stick.
But while having this connection, I would also like to use a WIFI connection (to an apple airport express in order so access local gadgets at home.)
i can manage to run both connections, but obviously I don't manage the routing well. As soon as I switch on the Apple Wifi connection, i loose internet access although the Wireless Broadband from the stick is still active. 
I am not proficient enough in windows routing to solve this myself and while searching for a long while found no hints online that would enable me to solve this. 
Thank you so much for any suggestions. 
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

The reason you lose internet is because when you connect to two networks you would have two routes, one via the usb stick and one via the wifi adapter.
There are a couple of options.

Change the adapter priority:

```
Navigate to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections 
Press the 'Alt' key to reveal the menus Click on 'Advanced' 
Click on 'Advanced Settings' 
Under Connections, select your USB stick and use the up button to increase it's priority.
```

Use a static IP address on your wifi:

```
Determine what IP address range your WiFi is on (probably 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x) by using IPCONFIG from a CMD prompt
Navigate to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
Go to your Wi-Fi adapter, right click and click Properties
Click on Internet Protocol Version 4, and click Properties
Click 'Use the following IP address' and enter your IP address, and Subnet Mask (LEAVE Default Gateway BLANK)
Click on 'Use the following DNS Servers' and enter your DNS Server
```

Your computer will now be able to communicate to the internet via your usb stick, and your lan via the wifi.